# no UnicodeError when using print with a default encoding set to ASCII

Tags: python, unicode

After reading:  [Dive into Python: Unicode Discussion](http://diveintopython.net/xml_processing/unicode.html)

I got curious to try printing my name in the `indic script`. I am using `v2.7.2` -

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.getdefaultencoding()
'ascii'
>>> name = u'\u0935\u0948\u092D\u0935'
>>> print name
वैभव
```

I was expecting `print name` to give me `UnicodeError` since the `defaultencoding` is set to `ASCII` so the auto-coercion to `ASCII` from `Unicode` shouldn't work.

What am I missing?

Comment: Anyone attempting to do serious Unicode work in Python had really best be using Python 3, not the legacy Python 2. But you will need [a supplementary regex library](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex), since `re` is broken on Unicode. And you really can’t do it, because of the horrible UCS‐²⁄₄ heisenbugs in Python.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[print uses sys.stdout.encoding](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PrintFails), not `sys.getdefaultencoding()`:

> When Python finds its output attached to a terminal, it sets the
>   sys.stdout.encoding attribute to the terminal's encoding. The print
>   statement's handler will automatically encode unicode arguments into
>   str output.

```
>>> import sys
>>> print(sys.stdout.encoding)
utf-8
>>> print(sys.getdefaultencoding())
ascii
>>> name = u'\u0935\u0948\u092D\u0935'
>>> print name
वैभव
```